# Hydra config: using another config as an input to multiple keys within a config

Tags: python, config, fb-hydra

Suppose I have the following directory structure for my hydra configs:

```
config
    |_config.yml
    operations
        |_subconfig.yml
```

`subconfig.yml` is

```yaml
param_1: foo
param_2: bar
```

and `config.yml` is:

```yaml
operations:
    signals:
        signal_a:
            param_1: foo
            param_2: bar
        signal_b:
            param_1: foo
            param_2: bar
    timestamps:
        ts_1:
            param_1: foo
            param_2: bar
```

Instead of repeating `param_1` and `param_2` in my main config, I want to use subconfig to fill these parameters as a default. I know that I could do it if I used the defaults list and just replaced param_1 and param_2 at the top level of my main config. But I`m struggling to figure it out how to replace the values of subkeys within the main config by the values within the subconfig file. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [packages](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/overriding_packages/). They allow you to place a the content of a config in a path independently of the config group it's in.

[image]